# SQLite não grava dados na tabela - table usuarios has no column named email

Tags: android, sqlite

alguém pode me ajudar com a seguinte dúvida??

Estou criando um APP simples em android e usando o SQLite, porém na hora de executar o APP e inserir os dados na area de cadastro de usuário, aparece a mensagem abaixo

---

> **E/SQLiteLog:** (1) table usuarios has no column named email
>
> **E/SQLiteDatabase**: Error inserting email=bruno@gmail.com nome=bruno
>   nascimento=1234 telefone=1234
>                     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table usuarios has no column named email (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT
>   INTO usuarios(email,nome,nascimento,telefone) VALUES (?,?,?,?)**

---

**CÓDIGO SQL**

```
public class Model extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String NOME_BANCO = "banco.db";
    public static final String TABELA = "usuarios";
    public static final String ID = "_id";
    public static final String NOME = "nome";
    public static final String EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String TELEFONE = "telefone";
    public static final String NASCIMENTO = "nascimento";
    private static final int VERSAO = 1;

    //CONSTRUTOR
    public Model(Context context) {
        super(context, NOME_BANCO, null, VERSAO);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        String sql = " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +TABELA+ "("
                + ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + NOME + " text,"
                + EMAIL + " text,"
                + TELEFONE + " text,"
                + NASCIMENTO + " text "
                + ")";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABELA);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

**CÓDIGO INSERT**

```
package com.example.crowwinter.projetoandroid;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by eduardo on 15/10/17.
 */

public class BancoController {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Model banco;

    long resultado;

    public BancoController(Context context){
        banco = new Model(context);
    }

    public String insereUsuario(String nome, String email, String telefone, String nascimento){
        ContentValues valores;

        db = banco.getWritableDatabase();

        valores = new ContentValues();

        valores.put(Model.NOME, nome);
        valores.put(Model.EMAIL, email);
        valores.put(Model.TELEFONE, telefone);
        valores.put(Model.NASCIMENTO, nascimento);

       resultado = db.insert(Model.TABELA, "null", valores);

        db.close();

        if (resultado == -1){
            return String.valueOf(resultado);
        }
        else if (resultado == resultado){
            return "Usuário já existente!";
        }

        else {
            return "Usuario cadastrado";
        }
    }
//    public  String listAll(){
//
//        db = banco.getWritableDatabase();
//
//        resultado = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM usuarios",null);

//    }
}
```

**CÓDIGO DA TELA CADASTRAR**

```
package com.example.crowwinter.projetoandroid;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Cadastrar_novo extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText nome;
    private EditText email;
    private EditText telefone;
    private EditText nascimento;
    private Button btnCadastrar;
    private Button btnVoltar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastrar_novo);


        nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        telefone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTelefone);
        nascimento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNascimento);
        btnCadastrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cadastrar);
        btnVoltar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_voltar);


        btnCadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                BancoController crud = new BancoController(getBaseContext());
                String resultado;

                String nomeString = nome.getText().toString();
                String emailString = email.getText().toString();
                String telefoneString = telefone.getText().toString();
                String nascimentoString = nascimento.getText().toString();

                if(nomeString.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(Cadastrar_novo.this,"Preencha todos os campos corretamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (emailString.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(Cadastrar_novo.this,"Preencha todos os campos corretamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (telefoneString.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(Cadastrar_novo.this,"Preencha todos os campos corretamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (nascimentoString.equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(Cadastrar_novo.this,"Preencha todos os campos corretamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }




                resultado = crud.insereUsuario(nomeString,emailString,telefoneString, nascimentoString);

               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), resultado, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });


    }



    public void onClickVoltar (View v){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Menu_Principal.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

Comment: Na primeira vez que você criou já tinha a coluna email? E coluna id pode ser nula? Porque vi que não colocou o NOT NULL no _id

Comment: Provavelmente esse erro acontece pq vc adicionou essa coluna após a tabela já ter sido criada e instalada dentro do device, desinstala o APP antes de rodar de novo, ou muda a versão do banco (Se estiver 1 coloca 2, e assim por diante) que vai resolver o problema

Comment: Ou então, caso você não queira trocar a versão, você pode desinstalar o app e rodar novamente

Comment: Leonardo Dias, alterar a versão do banco funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!!